# How can I replace a character in all the .php files inside a folder on OS X?

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I need to replace the following characters:

ă with a

â with a

î with i

ș with s

ț with t

The replacement must be case sensitive. For example if a letter is upper-case then it must be replaced with an upper-case letter.

I've read that I could use `sed` for this process but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone help me by writing the exact command that I must run in Terminal?

Comment: See also `echo ă â î ș ț | iconv -t us//TRANSLIT` which outputs `a ^a ^i s t` on  OS/X (and `a a i s t` on GNU).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `sed` is commonly used for these types of tasks, it isn't actually designed for them—its very name is **stream** editor.

The tool that is designed for non-interactive **file** editing is `ex`.  (`vi` is the "visual editor" form of `ex`.)  Particularly when you want to edit files in place, `ex` is a far superior tool to `sed`.

In this case the commands used are almost identical to the `sed` command given earlier, but they don't have to be.  The following is POSIX compliant (unlike `sed -i`).

```
for file in *.php; do ex -sc '%s/[ăâ]/a/ge | %s/ș/s/ge | %s/ț/t/ge | %s/î/i/ge | x' "$file" ; done
```

**Explanation:**

`-s` starts "silent mode" in preparation for batch processing.  `-c` specifies the command(s) to be executed.

`%` means to apply the following command to every line in the file.  The `s///` commands are fairly self-explanatory; the `e` flag at the end means that any errors (due to the pattern not being found) are suppressed and file processing will continue.

`|` is a command separator (not a pipe).

`x` tells `ex` to write any changes to the file (but only if there *were* changes) and exit.

---

If you want in-place file editing, `ex` is the tool of choice.  If you want to preview the changes before you make them, I'd recommend [using `tr` as @gardenhead suggests.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256165/135943)

(Of course, if you're using a proper version control system such as git, you could make the changes in place using `ex` and compare the files to the old version by running `git diff`.)

Comment: Have later discovered, the `e` flag to the `s` command is not specified in POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

`sed` will work, but this is much simpler with `tr`, which translates characters.

```
for file in *.php; do tr 'ăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ' 'aaistaaist' < "${file}" > "translated_${file}"
```

The `sed` equivalent (which you'll need on GNU systems, not OS/X where `tr` doesn't support multibyte characters) would be:

```
sed 'y/ăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ/aaistaaist/'
```

Comment: @Stephane, confused by the parenthetical statement.  Does GNU `tr` support multibyte characters, or does OS X `tr` support multibyte characters?  It seems that you're saying OS X `tr` doesn't, but that `sed` is only needed on GNU systems—which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the characters using the formula **`sed s/old_string/new_string/`**.

From manpage:

```
sed - stream editor for filtering and transforming text
```

```
s/regexp/replacement/
              Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that  portion  matched  with
              replacement.   The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pat‐
              tern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding  matching
              sub-expressions in the regexp.
```

If you've set of characters to replace, then I recommend creating file (e.g. `replace.sed`) containing the definition of replacement as follows:

```
$ cat replace.sed
s/ă/a/g
s/â/a/g
s/î/i/g
s/ș/s/g
s/ț/t/g
```

And then run you can execute as follows:

- **`sed -f replace.sed < old.php > new.php`**

  Which replace characters specified in `replace.sed` with new-ones from `old.php` and output to `new.php`
- **`sed -i -f replace.sed file.php`**

  Which replace `file.php` simultaneously replacing characters specified in `replace.sed`

  From manpage:

  ```
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

                edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
  ```

Or you can define simultaneously in a line like:

```
sed -e 's/ă/a/g' -e 's/â/a/g' -e 's/î/i/g' -e 's/ș/s/g' -e 's/ț/t/g'
```

---

For doing this operation for all `.php` files, you can use something like:

- **`find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' -f replace.sed '{}' \;`**
- **`for i in *.php; do sed -i '' -f replace.sed "$i"; done`**

Note: Use `-maxdepth 1` with `find` to limit for locating `*.php` in current directory only. Visit [`man sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Isn't this last `s` (-e 's/ș/s') expression incomplete?

Comment: @Kira see revised post

Comment: And how can I make it go through all the files inside a specific folder?

Comment: @Andrei see revised post. Note that `-i` option with `sed` will replace the old files

Comment: @Pandya, OS X uses BSD `sed`.  You have to provide an extension to the `-i` option or it won't work.  I recommend `-i .bak`.

Comment: `sed` has a `y` command for transliteration.

Comment: And how can I use this command to go inside all subfolders? `for i in *.php; do sed -i '' -f replace.sed "$i"; done`

Comment: @Andrei Have you tried `find` command given in answer?

Comment: @Pandya that command does not work. It gives the error `Find: illegal option -n`. I made it work however with the following command: `find test -iname "*.php" -exec sed -i '' -f test/replace.sed '{}' \;` where `test` is the folder containing the files.

Comment: @Andrei tell me if `find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' -f replace.sed '{}' \;` works (revised answer)?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a GUI tool, you can try [**jEdit**](http://jedit.org/). It has excellent search and replace functionality, including folder (directory) search. You can use regular expressions if you like. Hypersearch pops up a separate window with the results.

[image: jEdit search]

Comment: seems [software-rec](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/software-rec/info)!